# Communicate ViewModel on raise of error in Model

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm

I have an application that use the MVVM pattern and I would like to implement validation when the user is fill the information. For example if min is greater than max I want to disable the button in my view.

I have implemented IDataErrorInfo in the model. Here is my model:

```
public class MyModel : IDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string stock;
    public string Stock
    {
        get { return stock; }
        set { stock = value; }
    }

    private double min;
    public double Min
    {
        get { return min; }
        set { min = value; OnPropertyChange("Min"); }
    }

    private double max;
    public double Max
    {
        get { return max; }
        set { max = value; OnPropertyChange("Max"); }
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
           string  error = string.Empty;
            if (columnName == "Min" || columnName == "Max")
            {
                if (Min > Max)
                {
                    error = "Min can't be greater than Max";
                }
            }
            return error;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChange(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

And my ViewModel has a collection of MyModel (Bound to DataGrid) and a boolean property called CanUpdate. This CanUpdate is bound to IsEnabled Property of update button in my view.

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyModel> stocks;
    public ObservableCollection<MyModel> Stocks
    {
        get { return stocks; }
        set { stocks = value; }
    }

    private bool canUpdate = true;
    public bool CanUpdate
    {
        get { return canUpdate; }
        set { canUpdate = value; }
    }        

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        AddStocks();
    }

    public void AddStocks()
    {
        Stocks = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();
        Stocks.Add(new MyModel() { Stock ="Stock 1", Min = 10, Max=20 });
        Stocks.Add(new MyModel() { Stock = "Stock 2", Min = 5, Max = 15 });
        Stocks.Add(new MyModel() { Stock = "Stock 3", Min = 6, Max = 25 });
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChange(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

User can edit the Min and Max value from the DataGrid. While editing whenever a error raised in MyModel has to update the CanUpdate property in MyViewModel. Please guide me to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

In the view model, when adding items to the collection hook to their `PropertyChanged` event. In a handler analyse the `Error` property and modify `CanUpdate` accordingly.